# Optimal way to save spark sql dataframe to S3 using information stored in them

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql

I have dataframes with data like :

```
        channel  eventId1               eventId2               eventTs  eventTs2  serialNumber  someCode
        Web-DTB akefTEdZhXt8EqzLKXNt1Wjg    akTEdZhXt8EqzLKXNt1Wjg  1545502751154   1545502766731   4   rfs
        Web-DTB 3ycLHHrbEkBJ.piYNyI7u55w    3ycLHHEkBJ.piYNyI7u55w  1545502766247   1545502767800   4   njs
        Web-DTB 3ycL4rHHEkBJ.piYNyI7u55w    3ycLHHEkBJ.piYNyI7u55w  1545502766247   1545502767800   4   null
```

I need to save this data to S3 path looking like :

```
  s3://test/data/ABC/hb/eventTs/[eventTs]/uploadTime_[eventTs2]/*.json.gz
```

How can I proceed with this as I need to extract data from the partitions to write to S3 path: (the s3 path is a function of eventTs and eventTs2 present in the dataframes)

```
df.write.partitionBy("eventTs","eventTs2").format("json").save("s3://test/data/ABC/hb????")
```

I guess I can iterate over each row in the dataframe , extract the path and save to S3 but do not want to do that.

Is there any way to group by the dataframes on eventTs and eventTs2 and then save the dataframes to the full **S3 path**? Is there something more optimal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spark supports partitions like what we have in Hive. If number of distinct elements for eventTs, eventTs2 is less, partitions will be a good way to solve this.

Check the [scala doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter@partitionBy(colNames:String*):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter[T]) for more information around partitionBy.

Example usage:

```
val someDF = Seq((1, "bat", "marvel"), (2, "mouse", "disney"), (3, "horse", "animal"), (1, "batman", "marvel"), (2, "tom", "disney") ).toDF("id", "name", "place")
someDF.write.partitionBy("id", "name").orc("/tmp/somedf")
```

If you write the dataframe with the paritionBy on "id" and "name" the following directory structure will be created.

```
/tmp/somedf/id=1/name=bat
/tmp/somedf/id=1/name=batman

/tmp/somedf/id=2/name=mouse
/tmp/somedf/id=2/name=tom

/tmp/somedf/id=3/name=horse
```

The first and second partition becomes directories and all rows where id is equal to 1 and name is bat will be saved under the directory structure `/tmp/somedf/id=1/name=bat`, the order of the partitions defined in partitionBy decides the order of directories.

In your case, the partitions will be on eventTs and eventTS2.

```
val someDF = Seq(
        ("Web-DTB","akefTEdZhXt8EqzLKXNt1Wjg","akTEdZhXt8EqzLKXNt1Wjg","1545502751154","1545502766731",4,"rfs"),
        ("Web-DTB","3ycLHHrbEkBJ.piYNyI7u55w","3ycLHHEkBJ.piYNyI7u55w","1545502766247","1545502767800",4,"njs"),
        ("Web-DTB","3ycL4rHHEkBJ.piYNyI7u55w","3ycLHHEkBJ.piYNyI7u55w","1545502766247","1545502767800",4,"null"))
    .toDF("channel" , "eventId1", "eventId2", "eventTs",  "eventTs2",  "serialNumber",  "someCode")
someDF.write("eventTs", "eventTs2").orc("/tmp/someDF")
```

Creating a directory structure as follows.

```
/tmp/someDF/eventTs=1545502766247/eventTs2=1545502767800
/tmp/someDF/eventTs=1545502751154/eventTs2=1545502766731
```

Comment: except that I am looking at storing in S3. I am aware of this partitioning logic. Looking for a simple and clean way of doing this in S3.

Comment: Partitioning will be the simplest IMHO, unless the number of distinct elements in eventTS/eventTS2 is not in thousands and you don't have thousands of partitions in dataframe. In these cases you will end up creating thousands of very tiny files per partition.

Comment: Edited the question to be more clear on where I am stuck. The S3 path is a function of eventTs and eventTs2 and i doubt that we can save in S3 without specifying the full path the way you are storing in HDFS .

Comment: You can n save in S3 without specifying the full path, give it a try.

Comment: Works! Don;t know why I thought it won't. is there anyway to drop a column after partitioning based on that? Or use a UDF in partitionBy? As I do not want to format the dates and store new columns in yyyyMMdd format from epoch and increase the datasize. And I can't drop the original columns for granularity. As I have 3 partitioning columns which are different from the original data columns.

Comment: Partition columns are not stored as columns in the data. When hive/spark reads a partitioned data they creates the column on the fly by inferring it through the folder names. So you can create an additional column and use partitionBy on the new column, the new column is not stored in the data(the orc/parquet files) and this won't increase your storage.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186064/discussion-between-sudev-ambadi-and-tanvi).

Comment: I am running into a performance problem with this approach with mode.APPEND. Have asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54217803/optimizing-partitioned-data-writes-to-s3-in-spark-sql